# I don't understand Collation? (Mysql, RDBMS, Character sets)

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, oracle, rdbms

I Understand Character sets but I don't understand Collation. I know you get a default collation with every Character set in Mysql or any RDBMS but I still don't get it! Can someone please explain in layman terms?

Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: What do you think collation means?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The main point of a database collation is determining how data is sorted and compared.

**Case sensitivity of string comparisons**

```
SELECT "New York" = "NEW YORK";`
```

will return true for a case insensitive collation; false for a case sensitive one.

Which collation does which can be told by the `_ci` and `_cs` suffix in the collation's name. `_bin` collations do binary comparisons (strings must be 100% identical).

**Comparison of umlauts/accented characters**

the collation also determines whether accented characters are treated as their latin base counterparts in string comparisons.

```
SELECT "Düsseldorf" =  "Dusseldorf";
SELECT "Èclair" =      "Eclair";
```

will return true in the former case; false in the latter. You will need to read each collation's description to find out which is which.

**String sorting**

The collation influences the way strings are sorted.

For example,

- Umlauts `Ä Ö Ü` are at the end of the alphabet in the finnish/swedish alphabet `latin1_swedish_ci`
- they are treated as `A O U` in German DIN-1  sorting (`latin_german1_ci`)
- and as `AE OE UE` in German DIN-2 sorting (`latin_german2_ci`). ("phone book" sorting)
- In `latin1_spanish_ci`, "ñ" (n-tilde) is a separate letter between "n" and "o".

These rules will result in different sort orders when non-latin characters are used.

**Using collations at runtime**

You have to choose a collation for your table and columns, but if you don't mind the performance hit, you can force database operations into a certain collation at runtime using the `COLLATE` keyword.

This will sort `table` by the `name` column using German DIN-2 sorting rules:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
ORDER BY name COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
```

Using `COLLATE` at runtime will have performance implications, as each column has to be converted during the query. So think twice before applying this do large data sets.

MySQL Reference:

- [Character Sets and Collations That MySQL Supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html)
- [Examples of the Effect of Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collation-effect.html)
- [Collation issues](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collations.html)

Comment: +1 here too.  It's great when people take the time and explain things in a real useful manner.  Good job sir.

Answer (score 4):

Collation is information about how strings should be sorted and compared.

It contains for example case sensetivity, e.g. whether `a` = `A`, special character considerations, e.g. whether `a` = `á`, and character order, e.g. whether `O` < `Ö`.