# Understanding charset of a dynamic web page which contains charactors from different encodings

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, webserver

To understand, how the browser, web-server, db-server handles char-set encoding and how the final document which produces to the browser complies with the char-set which developer specifies at the top of the web page, Please look in to the following example.

There's a dynamic web page. When a browser requests the page, web-server/PHP loads some content from a MySQL database and integrate in to the page. In the MySQL DB, the collation (char-set) is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

In the web page the char-set is specified as "UTF-8 (`<meta charset="utf-8">`)

1) The final processed web page contains characters from both encodings?

2) Or web-server/PHP converting `latin1_swedish_ci` text in to `UTF-8`?

3) If the web page is anyhow encoded to `UTF-8` when sending to browser, 
There can be a possible doubt whether the `latin1_swedish_ci` has converted correctly. (in some situations, I've seen "?" for badly encoded characters)

4) If this is a buggy situation, what is the best approach to minimize the damage?

Comment: Some would say that this is the way to go: http://utf8everywhere.org

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708958/differences-between-utf8-and-latin1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324900/i-dont-understand-collation-mysql-rdbms-character-sets

Not an answer for your question, but I think you misunderstand about Mysql Collation and web charactorset.